# What is equivalent code segment/command of the matlab's bsxfun in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

I would like to perform same operation in python for the following line written in Matlab:

```
dot = sum(bsxfun(@minus, center, mid).*V, 2); where *center* is a row vector and *mid* is a matrix.
```

What will be the equivalent code segment/line in python?

Comment: Can you please show python code that you have tried? We can help you if you show us what problems you are running into.

Comment: @jakub thanks for your comment; my code is look like this: dot=np.sum((center-mid)*VV, axis=1).  Is it OK in python?

Comment: Yes! Your code is the python equivalent. Great job.